# iOS Architecture Decision

Tags: ios, architecture

I'm a new iOS developer looking to make my first app. I have list of a lot of exercises that I simply want the user to be able to browse through, read a description of the exercise when they tap on it, and select and view their favorite exercises.

I read "Beginning iPhone 4 Development" and decided that using CoreData would be my best bet. I've made significant progress with it (I'm able to browse the list and see a description when I tap it), but I'm running into a lot of data model conversion issues when I try to update models in CoreData with a new version. It seems like CoreData might not be exactly meant for what I want.

Long story short - what should I be using in iOS to accomplish an app like this?

A fair comparison might be a news app where the user scrolls a list, selects a story to read, and then can do things like favorite and share it. I just don't know what exactly they use for that.

Thanks!